# How to read and parse a CSV file from an Axios GET request in Node/Express?

Tags: node.js, express, parsing, axios, node-csv-parse

I'm creating a Node/Express backend that uses axios to make a GET request to this URL: `https://marknadssok.fi.se/Publiceringsklient/sv-SE/Search/Search?SearchFunctionType=Insyn&Utgivare=&PersonILedandeSt%C3%A4llningNamn=&Transaktionsdatum.From=&Transaktionsdatum.To=&Publiceringsdatum.From=2021-03-30&Publiceringsdatum.To=2021-03-30&button=export&Page=1`

When using a regular browser the response is a file download with the data in a CSV file.

Is there a way to read and parse this CSV file in the Node/Express backend that I'm building? I do not wish to persist the data to filesystem or anything. Simply use libraries such as "csv-parse" to turn this CSV file into an object for each row in the file.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

When I try the example where I read the file directly the jsonArray when I console.log it looks like this:

[image]

The actual CSV file seems to look just as it should. See here:

[image]

Comment: How's the result when you download and read the CSV file?

Comment: When I save to disk the actual .CSV file looks like it should. It's the parsing of the CSV-file that doesn't work. It spits out the same characters.

Comment: Any other suggestions on what could be the issue?

Comment: @JohanCarlberger — We can't tell why some code you haven't shown us is behaving that way. You need to provide a [mcve] (following the advice in [ask] is generally a good idea too).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following example. It downloads a CSV file, reads it, and removes it. However, the delimeter used in the CSV file you gave the link, form of `\x00`, the file looks like that. The best thing to do is to use a different CSV file or to parse that generated CSV file row by row. I think you can open a different question for this problem.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csvtojson');
const https = require('https');

let url = "https://marknadssok.fi.se/Publiceringsklient/sv-SE/Search/Search?SearchFunctionType=Insyn&Utgivare=&PersonILedandeSt%C3%A4llningNamn=&Transaktionsdatum.From=&Transaktionsdatum.To=&Publiceringsdatum.From=2021-03-30&Publiceringsdatum.To=2021-03-30&button=export&Page=1";

async function parseCSV(url) {

    const dest = __dirname + '/foo.csv'; // You can use uuid like packages to name the csv file

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);

        https.get(url, function (response) {
            response.pipe(file);
            file.on('finish', function () {
                file.close();
                csv({
                    noheader:true,
                    trim:true
                }).fromFile(dest).then(jsonArray => {
                    fs.unlinkSync(dest);
                    resolve(jsonArray);
                })
                
            });
        }).on('error', function (err) { // Handle errors
            fs.unlinkSync(dest);
            reject(new Error("Download failed."));
        });
    });
}
    

parseCSV(url).then( result => {
    result.forEach(row => {

        row = row.field1;
        console.log(row);
    });
});
```